# how to parse list of users in rest webservices in request payload

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jaxb

Need help in retrieving list of all users from request payload in REST webservice.

Body of the POST request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<users>
<user>
    <Email>User1@abc.com</Email>
    <URI>URI of user1</URI>
</user>
<user>
    <Email>User2@abc.com</Email>
    <URI>URI of user2</URI>
</user>
<users>
```

In REST webservice project, i created 2 classes like this.

**Users.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "users")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Users {
@XmlElement(name = "user")
private List<User> users = null;

public List<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}
}
```

**User.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class User {

private String userID;

public void setUserID(String userID){
    this.userID = userID;
}

public String getUserID(){
    return userID;
}
}
```

Now in my service class, i need to get users and parse each user. I am confused on how to do this.

```
@Path("/v1") 
public class WSOperations {

@POST
@Path("/users/{id}/groups")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response addUserGroup(@PathParam("id") String guid, Users users){

    String userID = "";
        try {
        for(User usr : users.getUsers()){
            userID = usr.getUserID();
        }
}
```

How to parse each user from list of users? Any help?

Comment: What's the exact problem? Are you running into JAXB problems where you can't parse the XML or something?

Comment: You could just do a for-loop on users, using your getting within your Users class. But again, when you say parse, are you just trying to extract the emails and URIs from users?

Comment: i updated the snippet with for loop that parses users class. I will update this thread once i run the services.

Comment: users.getUsers() is returning null. How do i get parse each user that was received? Pls help.

Comment: I am trying to extract email and uri from users

Comment: any updates please?